# Android: How to use TextView in placeholder of Glide or Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, placeholder, android-glide

i am using Glide or Picasso for loading the image like

```
Glide.with(context).load(POST_IMAGE).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_img).error(R.drawable.bg_480_800).into(image);
```

---

```
Picasso.with(context).load("image url").error(R.drawable.bg_480_800).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_img).into(holder.imageURL);
```

In these two, i'm using image as place holder from the drawable folder. Now i want to use text inside the place holder instead of image from drawable folder.

So, please help me to load text instead of loading image from the drawable folder

Comment: I suggest you to take one `TextView` behind your `ImageView` and after successful loading of Image set your visibility of Imageview to visible

Comment: How to know image was successfully loaded or not?

Comment: Picasso has CallBack you can use it like `Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
     .load(data.get(position).get("product_image"))
     .into(viewHolder.imgViewIcon, new Callback() {}`

Comment: You can use https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable for showing any character in place of image.

Answer (score 5):

Placeholder is a `Drawable`, so what you'll need is some kind of `Drawable` that is able to display text. [This](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable) library does exactly that, and does it pretty well.